# Kotlin: "Converting" Class do Object does not work as expected

Tags: kotlin, abstract-class

I was trying to convert `MyChallenge2` from a class to an object.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val myChallenge = MyChallenge()
    //val myChallenge2 = MyChallenge2()

    Challenge.enable()
}

abstract class Challenge {
    companion object {
        val challenges: ArrayList<Challenge> = arrayListOf()

        fun enable() {
            challenges.forEach { it.onEnable() }
        }
    }

    open fun onEnable() {}
}

class MyChallenge : Challenge() {

    init {
        challenges.add(this)
    }

    override fun onEnable() {
        println("Hello from myChallenge") // gets printed
    }
}

object /* why can't I convert this to an object?*/ MyChallenge2 : Challenge() {

    init {
        challenges.add(this)
    }

    override fun onEnable() {
        println("Hello from 2. Challenge") // doesn't get printed
    }
}
```

I was expecting for both `onEnable` methods to print their text in the console but it only happend with the class. What mistake did I do? In my thinking I'm adding the current class/object to the challenges array but when printing the array only the class showed up.

Comment: My guess: `MyChallenge2` is never accessed and thus the singleton instance is never created, meaning it is never registered with the `challenges` list. This sort of static registration is likely to lead to headaches and hurt maintainability; I recommend a different approach.

Comment: Uncommenting //val myChallenge2 = MyChallenge2()
leads to syntax error because you cannot instantiate an object.
If you remove the brackets,
val myChallenge2 = MyChallenge2
prints the text 
"Hello from 2. Challenge"
So what's the problem?